# How to clone all code and install all dependent software for a web application on new developers computer

Tags: node.js, git

I current have a web application that is essentially divided into 3 aspects.

1. Front End - The HTML, CSS and JavaScript web browser code.
2. Server - Express.js web server.
3. Database - MySQL database.

I store all the source code in a Git repository and can clone it to any developers computer. This all works fine.

My problem is encountered when I clone my repository to a new developers computer that does not have all the correct supporting applications installed. E.g. Node, MySQL, 7-zip, etc. We have to go through a laborious process of manually installing all these applications before the web application is able to run locally on their machine.

So my question is....

Is there someway that I can automate the installation of all this supporting software when or after cloning my repository from a git server so I don't have to go through this manual process each time?

Answer (score 1):

Configuration management systems are intended primarily for provisioning servers, but many developers also use them for development, particularly in conjunction with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com). If you needed to you could also use them to install software on the host.

I personally use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com) for this, but there are many other options like Puppet and Chef.

Comment: I had a look at Ansible and this seems essentially like a batch executable file. What are the benefits of using Ansible over say a simple .BAT file? Also what are the benefits of using Vagrant in this scenario? As I understand it, vagrant just starts a virtual machine which is good and would achieve my requirements I suppose, but then I would have to manage keeping this virtual machine up to date where as I would like to keep all the source code and resource configuration scripts in one place (i.e. Git), then the dev can just sync the code, run the script and start the application.

Comment: Ansible is higher-level than a shell script as it provides some degree of abstraction for many tasks. Also you can break your requirements into multiple roles eg have one to install and configure Nginx, and another for MySQL. Regarding Vagrant, what you would do is configure Vagrant to use Ansible as the provisioner and include the Vagrantfile and Ansible config in version control. That way when a new dev starts they can just clone the repository and run `vagrant up` to get started.

Comment: Great good description of the benefits of Ansible. However I still don't really see the benefit of vagrant in this scenario. Ansible would install all the relevant applications onto the devs computer then they can just run the server on their machine (i.e. localhost) without the additional complication of the virtual machine. So it would still have the same workflow you suggested. I.e. clone the repository, run Ansible, then start the node server. Although I guess mine has one additional step?

Comment: Vagrant allows you to isolate your development environment from the host to allow for different libraries and configurations, mirror your production environment exactly (so it runs on the same Linux distro with the same packages installed, for example) and use different versions of languages or libraries on different projects easily. In this scenario I'd have the Ansible playbook set up systemd or Supervisor to run the Node server for me, not run it manually.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Ansible can be used to install Windows packages via chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

Git and npm can restore the code and library dependencies from your application, you seem to need something to recover resorces that should be installed in the machine.

I recomend you to use some kind of image recovery tool that will install the machine from zero with all the necessary resorce.

Or a installer script to install all the programs you need something like https://ninite.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However, I don't think using an image recovery tool is a good option for this as the user/dev will loose all the other local data on their system. As for the installer script you suggested this is a good idea in general but it does not include Node or MySQL as options to add to the installer script.